# Understanding why "delete from not exists" becomes slow when subselect is fast

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a query thats bugging me which i've found a workaround for, but I would also like to understand why it is happening in the first place to learn something from it.

**Background:**
I have a database with "objects", and these objects have dynamic "properties" connected to them which the user can search and filter values on. We're aware that the optimal way to query is to run a single statement, but due to the complexity of various filters that can be applied to static and dynamic properties for each client, we've chosen to create a temporary search table at the beginning of each search query. We make a rough selection from the "objects" table and create the temporary table from that. Any further filter will make a selection and delete from the search table. When there are no more filters to apply, the final "search result" is presented to the user.

This specific case will add ~120.000 rows to the initial search table, which is pretty basic with just some ID's. We don't create any indexes on the search table as this hasn't proven necessary in any previous case. The properties table for this client consists of ~17.000.000 rows, and the important columns there are **object_id, language_id, propertytype_id and stringvalue**, which we have a combined BTREE index on.

This query returns fairly quickly, selecting all the ID's from properties table that contain the value we're filtering on:

```sql
SELECT o."id"
FROM "object_table" o
INNER JOIN "propertyvalue_table" pt
   ON o."id" = pt."object_id"
   AND pt."propertytype_id" = 41
   AND pt."language_id" = 1
GROUP BY o."id"
HAVING count(1) = <numberOfFilterValues>
   AND array_agg(LOWER(pt."stringvalue")) @> string_to_array(lower('<filtervalue(s)>'), ',')
```

But when i inject that query into the delete statement, it suddenly turns real bad:

```sql
DELETE FROM "temporary_search_table"
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM "object_table" o
   INNER JOIN "propertyvalue_table" pt
      ON o."id" = pt."object_id"
      AND pt."propertytype_id" = 41
      AND pt."language_id" = 1
   GROUP BY o."id"
   HAVING count(1) = <numberOfFilterValues>
      AND array_agg(LOWER(pt."stringvalue")) @> string_to_array(lower('<filtervalue(s)>'), ',')

   WHERE temporary_search_table."id" = o."id"
)
```

The EXPLAIN ANALYZE of the delete query took 15 minutes to complete, and my limited understanding of the explain is telling me that the subquery is being looped once per row in the temp table, but i don't understand why!
(the analyse contains a couple of extra joins which i've left out of the examples to reduce clutter)

```
Aggregate  (cost=29796768.84..29796768.85 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=1234845.455..1234845.456 rows=1 loops=1)                                                                                                                               
   ->  Seq Scan on testsearch  (cost=0.00..29796594.59 rows=69700 width=0) (actual time=74.967..1234814.642 rows=98515 loops=1)                                                                                                                
         Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 2))                                                                                                                                                                                                             
         Rows Removed by Filter: 30098                                                                                                                                                                                                         
         SubPlan 2                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
           ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=195.19..213.73 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=9.600..9.600 rows=0 loops=128613)                                                                                                                             
                 Group Key: qo.id                                                                                                                                                                                                              
                 Filter: ((count(1) = 1) AND (array_agg(lower((propertyvalue_1.stringvalue)::text)) @> '{inkognito}'::text[]))                                                                                                           
                 Rows Removed by Filter: 0                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                 InitPlan 1 (returns $0)                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                   ->  Index Scan using idx_propertyvalue_propertytypeid_languageid_stringvalue on propertyvalue  (cost=0.81..188.51 rows=182 width=4) (actual time=0.029..43.752 rows=45356 loops=1)                              
                         Index Cond: ((propertytype_id = 41) AND (language_id = 1) AND (lower((stringvalue)::text) = ANY ('{inkognito}'::text[])))                                                                                             
                 ->  Nested Loop  (cost=6.69..25.21 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=9.423..9.597 rows=0 loops=128613)                                                                                                                            
                       ->  Nested Loop  (cost=6.13..8.44 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.009..0.011 rows=1 loops=128613)                                                                                                                        
                             Join Filter: (qo.type_id = qotp.type_id)                                                                                                                                                                          
                             Rows Removed by Join Filter: 8                                                                                                                                                                                    
                             ->  Index Scan using pk_object_id on object qo  (cost=0.42..2.44 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=0.007..0.008 rows=1 loops=128613)                                                                       
                                   Index Cond: (id = testsearch.object_id)                                                                                                                                                                     
                             ->  HashAggregate  (cost=5.71..5.80 rows=9 width=4) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=9 loops=128613)                                                                                                                
                                   Group Key: qotp.type_id                                                                                                                                                                                     
                                   ->  Nested Loop  (cost=3.35..5.68 rows=9 width=4) (actual time=0.017..0.028 rows=9 loops=1)                                                                                                                 
                                         ->  Hash Join  (cost=3.20..4.63 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.015..0.021 rows=3 loops=1)                                                                                                             
                                               Hash Cond: (qp.id = qpp.propertyset_id)                                                                                                                                                         
                                               ->  Seq Scan on propertyset qp  (cost=0.00..1.25 rows=24 width=4) (actual time=0.002..0.005 rows=24 loops=1)                                                                              
                                                     Filter: (NOT deleted)                                                                                                                                                                     
                                                     Rows Removed by Filter: 1                                                                                                                                                                 
                                               ->  Hash  (cost=3.17..3.17 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=3 loops=1)                                                                                                            
                                                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 9kB                                                                                                                                              
                                                     ->  Index Scan using fki_propertyset_propertytype_propertytype_id on propertyset_propertytype qpp  (cost=0.14..3.17 rows=3 width=4) (actual time=0.003..0.005 rows=3 loops=1) 
                                                           Index Cond: (propertytype_id = 41)                                                                                                                                                  
                                         ->  Index Scan using fki_object_type_propertyset_propertyset_id on object_type_propertyset qotp  (cost=0.14..0.32 rows=3 width=8) (actual time=0.001..0.002 rows=3 loops=3)               
                                               Index Cond: (propertyset_id = qp.id)                                                                                                                                                            
                       ->  Index Scan using pk_propertyvalue on propertyvalue propertyvalue_1  (cost=0.56..16.76 rows=1 width=14) (actual time=1.269..1.444 rows=0 loops=128613)                                             
                             Index Cond: ((object_id = ANY ($0)) AND (object_id = testsearch.object_id) AND (propertytype_id = 41) AND (language_id = 1))
```

I usually resort to a CTE to solve these cases where i simply don't understand the postgresql well enough, and the below works as i assumed the statement above would.

```sql
WITH relevant_object_ids AS (
   SELECT o."id"
   FROM "object_table" o
   INNER JOIN "propertyvalue_table" pt
      ON o."id" = pt."object_id"
      AND pt."propertytype_id" = 41
      AND pt."language_id" = 1
   GROUP BY o."id"
   HAVING count(1) = <numberOfFilterValues>
      AND array_agg(LOWER(pt."stringvalue")) @> string_to_array(lower('<filtervalue(s)>'), ',')
)
DELETE FROM "temporary_search_table"
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM relevant_object_ids
   WHERE temporary_search_table."id = relevant_object_ids."id"
)
```

Comment: The execution plan is not complete (no delete node), and the names are all different than in your query. Could you remedy that to ease the reader's job?